# Orchard 1.8 - Creating a part corresponding to a 1-n relationship

Tags: c#, model, orchardcms, relationship, orchardcms-1.8

I need to create a part to attach to an existing content type. The model associated to this part has no variables except a list of items, corresponding to a 1-N relationship with the data contained in a table I created. If I use the Record approach, creating a Model containing only the list, it will generate a "fake" table with no other data except its Id. This is the current code:

```
**Model**
public class MyPartRecord : ContentPartRecord
{ public virtual IList<OtherRecord> MyList { get; set; } }

public class MyPart : ContentPart<MyPartRecord>
{
    public IList<OtherRecord> MyList {
        get { return Record.MyList; }
}

public class OtherRecord
{
    public virtual string Var1 { get; set; }
    public virtual int Var2 { get; set; }
}

**Migration**
SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("MyPartRecord", table => table
            .ContentPartRecord());

SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("OtherRecord", table => table
            .Column<int>("Id", column => column.PrimaryKey().Identity())
            .Column<string>("Var1")
            .Column<int>("Var2")
            .Column<int>("MyPartRecord_Id")
            );
```

I'm not convinced by this approach, so I'd like to know if I can create the 1-N relationship using only the Infoset approach and eliminating the need to create the "fake" table in the migration, or if there is some smarter way to do it using the Record approach.

**UPDATE**

I tried to use the infoset approach but I can't make it work. I changed my files like this:

```
**Model**
public class MyPart : ContentPart
{
    public IList<OtherRecord> MyList {
        get { return this.Retrieve(x => x.MyList, new List<OtherRecord>()); }
}

**Migration**
SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("OtherRecord", table => table
            .Column<int>("Id", column => column.PrimaryKey().Identity())
            .Column<string>("Var1")
            .Column<int>("Var2")
            .Column<int>("MyPart_Id")
            );
```

But when the driver calls the get method I always receive an empty list, so I don't think that the relations are built properly.

Comment: You absolutely can and should store that list in the infoset, unless it is designed to be queried on. There are actually multiple possible approaches. You could also consider taxonomies, for example. More information on the specific scenario would help.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot make it work with the infoset approach. I added to my first post some more details about the code that I tried to use.

Comment: Well, you're not really using the Infoset. Your code implements some sort of halfway logic that uses the Infoset to link to a table. This looks like the worst of all worlds. You should do it all in the Infoset.